# How to connect my local postgresql with my local ip address

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My question is, I install the postgresql in my Mac, then I want to connect my postgresql with my local IP address.

For example, my local IP address is: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx, I want to command as`psql -U username -d dbname -h 10.xxx.xxx.xxx` to instand of command `psql -U username -d dbname -h 127.0.0.1`.

I has added my IP address to `pg_hba.conf`, and changed `listen_address` in `postgresql.conf` to `listen_address = '*'`, but not worked.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: check if ports are open between 127.0.0.1 and 10.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: I mean 10.xxx.xxx.xxx equals 127.0.0.1 I have only one computer.

Comment: Have you tried connecting normally without -h option

Comment: yes，I try connect with 127.0.0.1, and successed. But 10.xxx.xxx.xxx, failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your local IP in `/etc/hosts` file and then try again. Like below:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.xxx.xxx.xxx  localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run both and postgres and grafan from containers you have to check

```
$docker network inspect bridge
```

In my case there should be ip:172.17.0.4 and port: 16 instead of lochalhost and 5432. Those ip and port docker assigns automatically while makes the bridge between containers I guess.